# OCaml Emacs Tuareg: Evaluate phrase keyboard shortcut, and how to display actual greek symbols?

Tags: emacs, ocaml, tuareg

Two questions about Emacs Tuareg for OCaml:

1. I have seen some configurations where it displays an alpha symbol instead of a'. How can I turn this on?
2. What is the keyboard shortcut for "evaluate phrase" or "evaluate buffer"?

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer part (2):

- To start an Ocaml top-level: `C-c C-s`
- To evaluate a phrase: `C-x C-e`
- To evaluate a buffer: `C-c C-b`
- To evaluate a region: `C-c C-r`

Answer (score 2):

Launch the tuareg mode (e.g. by `M-x tuareg-mode`), and look at its documentation pressing `C-h m`.

The symbols are displayed by the sym-lock mode only works for Xemacs and its variants I'm afraid, but you'll find how to configure it in your .emacs in the help mentioned above. The shortcut to execute a statement is `C-x C-e` (see section 'Special keys' of the help).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you mean for part 1 of your question, but I have a font-lock-mode keyword to display the `lambda` keyword as the Greek lambda symbol, which could be adapted to do what you ask. It only requires that font-lock-mode be enabled. (I didn't write it, just found it floating around somewhere).

```
;; real lisp hackers use the lambda character
;; courtesy of stefan monnier on c.l.l
(defun sm-lambda-mode-hook ()
  (font-lock-add-keywords
   nil `(("\\<lambda\\>"
   (0 (progn (compose-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)
        ,(make-char 'greek-iso8859-7 107))
      nil))))))
(add-hook 'emacs-lisp-mode-hook 'sm-lambda-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'lisp-interactive-mode-hook 'sm-lamba-mode-hook)
(add-hook 'scheme-mode-hook 'sm-lambda-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can look to [my existing configs](http://github.com/alexott/emacs-configs/blob/master/rc/emacs-rc-pretty-lambda.el), based on the code from EmacsWiki with some extensions - function to handle conversion from text to chars, and example of it use for erlang mode - you can change it for ocaml mode also

P.S. but this code has one disadvantage - it also displays these characters inside strings and comments